# azure data factory v2 ingest files from data lake with different filenames and structure

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, flat-file, data-ingestion

I've been tasked to ingest flat files from data lake storage.

They are multiple files and will be stored in the same logical folder.
The contents and structure of these files are different.
each times a new file is added with the same structure of a previous one, the filename will be different.
eg.

> filename_1.csv

contents structure

```
col1, col2, col3
```

next time the same file is uploaded with different data, it can be called

> january_new-data-1.csv

I've created the sink tables for each file.

how can I create adF pipelines to to ingest these files dynamically?
Is it even possible?

I'm thinking these files need to be separated into their own logical folders first, yes?

Comment: Is it copied to different tables according to the number of columns in the file?

Comment: some of the files can have the same number of columns but the columns headers will be different

Comment: We can change `Get Metadata2` activity to get `Structure`, it will retrun column headers of the file. Then we can use one of the column headers   as a `Switch` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can ingest these files dynamically. These files no need to be separated into their own logical folders first. I created a simple test. Copied to different tables according to column count in the files through one pipeline.
I created two tables, one has 3 columns and the other one has 4 columns:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[emp_stage](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [age] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Entities](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [name] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [age] [int] NULL,
    [city] [varchar](100) NULL
)
```

In ADF, we can perform different copy activities by judging the number of different columns via Switch activity.

1. I have two csv files in my data lake "input" container. `emp.csv` contains 3 columns, its corresponding table name is `[dbo].[emp_stage]`. `january_new-data-1.csv` contains 4 columns, its corresponding table name is `[dbo].[Entities]`.
   [image]
2. So I created a dataset to "input" container. Add dynamic content `*.csv`  and select `First row as header`.
   [image]
3. Use `Get MetaData1` activity to get the Child Items.
   [image]
   Child Items is as follows:
   [image]
4. Use `Foreach1` activity, add dynamic content `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`.
   [image]
5. Inside `Foreach1` activity, we can creat a dataset and key in dynamic content `@item().name`. We can pass the file name dynamically to `Get Metadata2` activity.
   [image]
   This way we can dynamically specify a file in the container.
   [image]
6. Use `Switch1` activity, add expression `@string(activity('Get Metadata2').output.columnCount)` to convert the output of `Get Metadata2` activity to string type. `Get Metadata2` activity will get the column count of the specified file.
   [image]
7. I will get two cases here, '3' and '4'. So by default is '3', we will go to `Copy activity1`.
   [image]
8. When case '4', we will go to `Copy activity2`. `Copy activity1` and `Copy activity2` use the same data source. This data source we defined previously at Step 5. They sink to different tables.
   [image]
9. After debug, I can see the result in my tables.
   [image]